# Override Lift ajaxRadio toForm default markup

Tags: scala, lift

I have ajaxRadio in my form, but Lift generates undesirable markup for me (it wraps input tag with span, and I would like to label tag).
It is possible to override default toForm function or exactly override method htmlize, which is called

```
object ChoiceHolder {  
    var htmlize: ChoiceItem[_] => NodeSeq = c => (<span>{c.xhtml} {c.key.toString}<br/> </span>)  
  }
```

So how to get, that around input tags will be labels and not spans?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that the `ChoiceItem` is something like

```
val choiceItem = ChoiceItem("Some key", <input type="radio" value="val" name="somename" />)
```

and you call the `toForm` method as follows

```
ChoiceHolder(Seq(choiceItem)).toForm
```

you could use

```
ChoiceHolder.htmlize = ci => evalElemWithId((id, e) => e ++ <label for={id}>{ci.key.toString}</label>)(ci.xhtml)
```

which might return something like

```
NodeSeq(<input name="somename" type="radio" value="val" id="F212153483008MMP"></input>, <label for="F212153483008MMP">Some key</label>)
```

or, if you want to wrap the label around

```
ChoiceHolder.htmlize = ci => evalElemWithId((id, e) => <label for={id}>{e} {ci.key.toString}</label>)(ci.xhtml)
```

which gives you

```
NodeSeq(<label for="F689721302326S3S"><input name="somename" type="radio" value="val" id="F689721302326S3S"></input>Some key</label>)
```

A bit complicated: `evalElemWithId` (import `net.liftweb.util.Helpers.evalElemWithId`) takes the first element of a `NodeSeq` (e.g. choiceItem.xhtml), and adds an `id` attribute to it. Afterwards the anonymous function will be called which receives this id so that you can use it in the `for` attribute of the label.

**Edit**
Note that `ChoiceHolder.htmlize` is kind of a global function which will be called through all `ChoiceHolder.toForm` calls. So it only makes sense to globally change it if you want to have the same layout everywhere.

If you just want to have a distinct layout in one case, you’re probably better off just calling some `choiceToForm` method.

Comment: thanks a lot for help, but I don't know how to use your code. I tried to use your ChoiceHolder.htmlize, but compiler warns me, that it doesn't know about evalElemWithId. I can't find out where to write this code. To own class? Create new object?

Comment: `import net.liftweb.util.Helpers.evalElemWithId`

Comment: @kajo: Sorry, I’ve actually made an error. Should be fine now…

Comment: I already don't know, but my compiler in Eclipse still warns me with error and mvn jetty:run too - error: value evalElemWithId is not a member of object net.liftweb.util.Helpers - I found function with same name in HttpHelpers, but with no result - still compiling errors.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn’t know either. This was only introduced in Lift 2.2. So either you upgrade or you could just see how the function is implemented in HttpHelpers.

Answer (score 1):

So finally I found solution by myself.
It's not so clean I would expected, but it works!

So for future generation with same problem - I wrap ajaxRadio with my own function:

```
choicesToMyForm( SHtml.ajaxRadio( ... ) )
```

and this function looks like:

```
def choicesToMyForm(choices : ChoiceHolder[String]) : NodeSeq =
{
    choices.flatMap( c => (<label>{c.xhtml} {c.key.toString}</label>) )
}
```